# For loop in excel vba not showing values to cell

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm trying to use "for loop" to get some specific values, code runs perfect but values do not print to destination.
subcode, where the problem is, looks like this :

```
lastRow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 5 To lastRow

    radius = Range("C" & i).Value
    spacing = Range("L" & i).Value

    Select Case radius
      Case 0 To 450
        spacing = 6
      Case 451 To 750
        spacing = 9
      Case 751 To 2000
        spacing = 18
    End Select

Next i
```

Comment: what should _"destination"_ mean?

Comment: spacing = Range("L" & i).Value is just assign the cell value to a variable by value. Set spacing = Range("L" & I) is set the spacing variable refer to a range object.

Comment: @HTH   Destination is "L" Column, ranges from 5th Row to the Last Row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are storing a *value* from `Range("L" & i).Value` to the *variable* `spacing`. Then, in your `For` loop you are assigning a new *value* to the *variable*, but you are not setting the *range* (cell) to that value.

The below, albeit shoddy, will work for you.

```vb
lastRow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 5 To lastRow

    radius = Range("C" & i).Value

    Select Case radius
      Case 0 To 450
        Range("L" & i).Value = 6
      Case 451 To 750
        Range("L" & i).Value = 9
      Case 751 To 2000
        Range("L" & i).Value = 18
    End Select

Next i
```

Comment: how did you guess those "L" column ranges from?

Comment: @HTH OP is trying to set `spacing` value in the for loop but he is setting the variable and not the range. Hence the output is not going to the cell.

Comment: The lack of info for the _"destination"_ was my first comment. But guessing it was to be a `Range` (instead of some row height, or something) and in column "L", is to far from me